# Time average of $\cos^2 x$ function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How do I find the time average of $\cos^2(3-wt)$ ?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: What is the definition of time average, and is "w" a constant?

Comment: What is the definition of time average of a function? And have you seen trigonometric identities such as $2\cos^2x= 1+\cos 2x$?

Answer (score 2):

For a one variable function $f(t)$ with period $T$ the time average function is defined as

$$\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} dt f(t)$$

so what you need to compute is the following integral

$$\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt\cos^2(3-\omega t) $$

where $T$ is the smallest strictly positive number such that:

$$f(t+T)=f(t) $$

Comment: Important: T is _the smallest strictly positive_ number verifying $f(t+T)=f(t)$!